# World Championship where there are more than one National team?

Tags: trivia, international-sports

Does exist any speciality where is it possible to see more that one team from the same Country at the World Championship events?

Comment: It depends about the sports, if they are sports with only one national team per category or not. It depends about the difference between "country" and "nation" too. For exemple, the UK is a country, but four nations are represented with each a national team in football : England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland. On another hand, in rugby, there is one only Irish national team which represents both Northern Ireland (belonging to the UK) and the Republic of Ireland.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It very definitely happens in a number of sports.  I can immediately think of bob-sleigh, where it is very common in both Olympic and World Championship competition to have multiple teams from the same country. In the most recent 4 man bob world championships Germany finished 1,2 and 4 [[1]](http://www.fibt.com/races-results/results.html?tx_pxresults_pi1[sport]=BSM&tx_pxresults_pi1[season]=2014&tx_pxresults_pi1[event]=WCH&tx_pxresults_pi1[searchmode]=2&tx_pxresults_pi1[event_id]=164813)

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is going to depend a lot on how you define "World Championship" and "team" (in particular, is one person a team?), so here's a community wiki list:

- Beach volleyball: this definitely has a World Championship, and multiple pairs from one country can enter.

Comment: World Championship it should be the most important tournament that give the World Champion title, I know that in some sport it is easyer to determine that than other sports. For that question the "team" i composed by more person and the name of the team should be USA1, USA2 and so on

Comment: You should edit your question to contain that information.

Answer (score 2):

In the [2000 Rugby League World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Rugby_League_World_Cup) both New Zealand and a New Zealand Maori team competed alongside each other.  In terms of the major "team" sports (eg Soccer, Rugby, Cricket etc) this is the only occasion that this has happened.